# How can I remove certain CSS attributes from a stylesheet?

Tags: css

This would be particularly helpful when making a new "child stylesheet" which overwrites some parts of the "parent stylesheet".

For example, when making a [RTL version of a WordPress theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Right-to-Left_Language_Support), I would keep all horizontal positioning attributes and delete the rest.

Is there a way or a tool to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I think the most viable solution would be to use php or the like to write in the css file directly. So in the css.php file:

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
if($rtl){
    $direction = "right";
}else{
     $direction = "left";
}?>
.selector{
    <?php echo $direction; ?>: 20px;
}
....
```